# YouTube Video HTML 5 Support

Tags: html

I got a Youtube video to place on a website. How can I place it on a website with HTML 5 so that those that got iDevices (iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad) can view it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you currently can just use the regular YouTube EMBED method and those iDevices will detect it correctly and jump to the YouTube App from Safari.  I've got a first gen iPod Touch and I'm pretty sure I've come across regular embedded videos on blogs.  Have you tried it or am I just plain nuts (and wrong)?

I agree with the assumption that an HTML5 way to place a YouTube video would be "better" and more future proof.  Flash is dead.

Comment: Yes I used the normal Youtube EMBED method and it works from my iPhone and iPod Touch. Thanks